# How can I add my project DLL to use intelligence with notepad++?

Tags: dll, reference, notepad++, dll-injection

I was thinking to write code from notepad++ and wanted to get intelligence of my project DLL, but since I am not able to find from where I can add my project DLL with notepad++.

Is it possible to add my project reference with notepad++?

Can we add more than DLL to notepad++ of my project to achieve intelligence?

Please help me on this, suggestions and feedback are welcome.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I do not understand your question. What are you trying to do? Possibly you need to write a Notepad++ plugin?

Comment: Hi @AdrianHHH, 

actually i was trying to add reference of my project dll (which is c# based) with notepad++ to achieve the intellicence.

like currently if on notepad++, after selecting language we are able to get intellicence.

The same thing i wanted to achieve with my project using notepad++, So Is it possible and if yes then please guide me?

Comment: Check out the NppExec plugin for Notepad++.